# Node.JS website deployed to Firebase works, but google console and isitdownrightnow.com shows 404 errors

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, google-search, firebase-tools, google-developers-console

I created a website in React & NodeJS, then deployed it to the firebase. It works fine. I connected a domain to it, it works fine as well, I can open it in browser, everything is good.

But when I tried to check it on [google search console](https://search.google.com/search-console) [httpstatus](https://httpstatus.io/) or [isitdownrightnow](https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/) they inform me, that website is down with 404 error.

I tried going to the IP address directly, without using domain, and it does display some 404 error, not the one from my website. Is that the reason?

What can I do, so my website would be visible to google and other services? What could be the issue? For me, in the browser, as a user, everything just works fine.

My firebase.json looks like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./.firebase/app/hosting",
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "europe-west1"
    },
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/robots.txt",
        "destination": "/robots.txt"
      }
    ]
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  }
  
}
```

response header according to httpstatus.io:

```
Status code
404

Status message
Not Found 

connection
close

content-length
5188

cache-control
max-age=3600

content-type
text/html; charset=utf-8

etag
"7d57700b9ea4bc474440b65918733f5a8a6ddf3ab73aa6d701d49de1f464b7bb"

last-modified
Tue, 18 Jul 2023 19:57:46 GMT

strict-transport-security
max-age=31556926

accept-ranges
bytes

date
Sun, 23 Jul 2023 07:48:10 GMT

x-served-by
cache-ams21055-AMS

x-cache
HIT

x-cache-hits
1

x-timer
S1690098491.845516,VS0,VE1

vary
x-fh-requested-host, accept-encoding

alt-svc
h3=":443";ma=86400,h3-29=":443";ma=86400,h3-27=":443";ma=86400
```

Regards

UPDATE:
I found out that in browser, the page does return 404 header, but works fine.[image]